# Taylor series of $\log(1+ix)$ and $e^{ix}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

In this proof about a central limit theorem [(see Theorem 2.6.2)](https://books.google.at/books?id=_5Xqo02nzO0C&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=mcleish+martingale+central&source=bl&ots=g7BWO0LXSE&sig=D2SGal-atfz-E6Q6zpTuzplICXY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJw6aQ1Z7TAhVMBMAKHRMjDigQ6AEIajAI#v=onepage&q=mcleish%20martingale%20central&f=false), the author writes the Taylor series for $\log(1+ix)$ and $e^{ix}$ and use it for the calculation for the complex random variable $e^{itS_n}$.

The taylor series for $\log(1+ix)$ only converges for $|x|<1$ or am I wrong?

I also found this argument in other similar proofs but in my opinion the calculation of $e^{itS_n}$ should just hold on the set where $|tS_n|<1$.